# Foreign key issue while insert or delete

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, postgresql-9.5

i have 3 tables below

books

[image]

users

[image]

and 
 test.users_books with foreign keys

```
CREATE TABLE test.users_books (
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES test.users(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES test.books(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE

);
```

while am trying to insert in to

```
INSERT INTO test.users_books values(11)
```

getting below error

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "users_books" violates foreign key constraint "users_books_user_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(11) is not present in table "users".
********** Error **********

ERROR: insert or update on table "users_books" violates foreign key constraint "users_books_user_id_fkey"
SQL state: 23503
Detail: Key (user_id)=(11) is not present in table "users".
```

how to insert 11 into this table with foreign key the id 11 having in books table.
is there any condition need insert for this table please let meknow

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES test.books(id) ` <<-- typo??

Comment: `(user_id) REFERENCES test.books(id)` makes no sense. Why would a `user_id` reference a book? `users_books` is missing a column `book_id` that references `books` (and `user_id` should not be the primary key - that way each user can only have a single book)

Comment: @ wildplasser no  typo mistake

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name  am using 9.5 version of postgres

Comment: Your test.users_books has user id only ?

Comment: @sanooj yes its true

Comment: @joe. Why would you do that?  This schema makes no sense as it is written, so perhaps you could describe why a book id is a user?